# From which category are products from search result

Tags: product, category, advanced-search

Is there any way to find out - to get in some variable, information about category from which the products that shows up from search result are.

For example my specific situation: In advance search I insert one searchable attribute and for result I get 5 products. This 5 products share same attribute  and it is also for sure from same category ( webshop have just two root category and ever category has specific and unique range of attributes ) .

So I need ( in code ) the category name or ID from which this listed products are.

Answer (score 2):

Will it work for you?

```
    $collection = $product->getCategoryCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->order('LENGTH(path) DESC');

    $categoryItems = $collection->load()->getIterator();
    $category      = current($categoryItems);
    if ($category) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
        return $category;
    }
```